# Technological based solution needed for a real world problem of transferring a physical object between two untrusted parties

Tags: provable-security, transport-security

Suppose I have a physical object A. Another person also has some rights over the object A. After some litigations, a schedule has been made under which object A will be passed for some time to the other person (e.g. if I possess A then I must give it to the person at a specific time and then after some agreed upon time he will return it to me). Now, the problem is that I cannot trust the other person and he cannot trust me. At any time when we can cheat each other we will definitely cheat. In this situation, what could be a technologically viable solution for handing over the physical object between untrusting parties? (For example GPS based system or anything of that sort). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I close this question because it's not in the realm of cryptography. Our [tag:transport-security] is about secure transport of information. The largest physical entities we study the secure movement of are particles, like photons, in quantum key distribution. When we move larger physical objects (like sheets of paper in an opaque envelope), we tend to _assume_ this is secure.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it's tricky to say if there's a cryptographic solution to it. I'll be up-voting, but not yet re-opening it.